# Python Encode Spaces are incorrectly encoded

Tags: python, encoding, urlencode

I have a dictionary as follows

```
params = {
        'response_type': 'token',
        'client_id': o_auth_client_id,
        'redirect_url': call_back_url,
        'scope': 'activity heartrate location'

}
print urllib.urlencode(params)
```

and um encoding it

but in results

> redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8084%2Fagile_healtg%2Faccess_token%2F&response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxx&scope=activity+heartrate+location

um getting something like above 
Unfortunately spaces are encoded as + signs

but the results should be

> scope=activity%20nutrition%20heartrate

how may I achieve the correct encode for spaces in python ?

Comment: This is correct encoding for space in the query. Try `"http://www.google.com/?" + urllib.urlencode({"q": "http query string"})`.

Comment: @zvone i need spaces as  %20  encoding spaces as + is incorrect

Comment: But it isn't incorrect. `+` is the correct encoding for a space in a querystring parameter. `%20` is the encoding for a space in a path element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program might do what you ask for.

```
import urllib

def my_special_urlencode(params):
    return '&'.join('{}={}'.format(urllib.quote(k, ''), urllib.quote(v, '')) for k,v in params.items())

params = {
        'response_type': 'token',
        'client_id': 'xxxxxx',
        'redirect_url': 'http://example.com/callback',
        'scope': 'activity heartrate location'

}

print my_special_urlencode(params)
```

Result:

```
redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxx&scope=activity%20heartrate%20location
```

Comment: Yes this  is the solution

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for the [urlencode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode).

The `quote_plus` method is used to change the spaces to plus symbol when it comes to passing key values. You can use `unquote_plus` method to remove the plus symbols and then `quote` to encode it in the format you want.

**You basically need to use the `quote` method for your parameters**

Comment: This is what I got redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8084%2Fagile_healtg%2Faccess_token%2F&response_type=token&client_id=xxxx&scope=activity%2Bheartrate%2Blocation I didnt got %20 @George D

Comment: the url has to be encoded using the `urlencode` method and the other parameters using the `quote`.